# Simple rational expression that Mathematica cannot simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want Mathematica to simplify some simple expressions of this kind:

```
(p^2 q^p + (q^s) (s^2) )/q
```

The output that I expect is

```
p^2 q^(p-1) + (q^(s-1)) (s^2)
```

I tried with various assumption without results..

Edit: thank you for the replies. Ok, in that example Expand is fine but if I have something slightly more complicated

```
((p^2 q^p (q + q^p))/(1 + q^p) + (q^s (q + q^s) s^2)/(1 + q^s))/q^2
```

In this case expand will give me 4 terms while I am fine with

```
 (p^2 q^(p-2) (q + q^p))/(1 + q^p) + (q^(s-2) (q + q^s) s^2)/(1 + q^s)
```

Comment: `In[63]:= (p^2 q^p + (q^s) (s^2))/q // Expand

Out[63]= p^2 q^(-1 + p) + q^(-1 + s) s^2`

Comment: If you are not satisfied with what `Expand` gives for the case in your Edit, then you need to give a mathematical criterion for what you consider "fine". How would Mathematica know otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

```
Expand[(p^2 q^p + (q^s) (s^2))/q]
```